# How can one convert a path with relative components to an absolute path in a windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Given a path with relative components:

```
c:\foo\..\temp\file.txt
```

I want to "remove/expand" the relative part,

```
c:\temp\file.txt
```

How can I convert a path with relative components to an absolute path in a windows batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "relative=c:\foo\..\temp\file.txt"

for %%a in ("%relative%") do set "absolute=%%~fa"

echo %relative% = %absolute%
```

Use the modifiers in `for` ([technet documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx)) replaceable parameters to get the full path to the indicated element (see `for /?` for the full list)

```
%~I        Expands %I which removes any surrounding quotation marks ("").
%~fI       Expands %I to a fully qualified path name.
%~dI       Expands %I to a drive letter only.
%~pI       Expands %I to a path only.
%~nI       Expands %I to a file name only.
%~xI       Expands %I to a file extension only.
%~sI       Expands path to contain short names only.
%~aI       Expands %I to the file attributes of file.
%~tI       Expands %I to the date and time of file.
%~zI       Expands %I to the size of file.
%~$PATH:I  Searches the directories listed in the PATH environment variable and
           expands %I to the fully qualified name of the first one found. If
           the environment variable name is not defined or the file is not
           found by the search, this modifier expands to the empty string.
```

Will work the same for files or folders and it is the same if they exist or not.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy. If you are working with folders, use this:

```
@echo off
set rel=c:\foo\..\temp
set abs=
pushd %rel%
set abs=%CD%
popd
echo relative path is %rel%
echo absolute path is %abs%
```

Let's take a look at the code. Wherever you are, `pushd %rel%` will save your current location and change directory to `%relpath%`, means `c:\foo\..\temp`. After changing the directory `%CD%` will contain the resolved path `C:\temp`. This path will be stored in the variable `%abs%`. Afther this step you do `popd` which will take you back to the directory stored with `pushd`. So at the end you've resolved the relative path by jumping to it, saved it in `%abs%` and jumped back to your current directory.

EDIT: If you are dealing with files this will work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET rel=c:\foo\..\temp\file.txt
FOR /f %%i IN ("%rel%") DO (
    SET abs=%%~di%%~pi%%~ni%%~xi
)
ECHO %abs%
```

Comment: Thank you. I am working with filenames not directories. I have updated my question to make it more clear. I am not sure, whether your method will also work for filenames, but it is good to know if one deals with directories.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I've edited my post and added the handling for files.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an argument, you can expand it using `~f`, for example `%~f1`.

If it's not, you can make it an argument to a subroutine:

```
call :absPath %RELPATH%
exit /b

:absPath
echo Absolute path: %~f1
```